# how to delete comments on facebook comment box?

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

Right now i am using facebok comment box and i have made my self as moderator for this comment box.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=288593874528383";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I have specified my admin in meta tag

> `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>`

What is the way to delete any comments given by any user on facebook commentbox?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 1):

Specify fb:app_id as meta property in head of the html doc, like:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456"/>
```

and repalce 123456 with your app id. Than, if you are the admin of the fb app, you should be able to  moderate the comments using this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [graph API to delete comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/).  Does that help?

Comment: Here it show a link https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_475058873552_14173716
Here '19292868552_475058873552_14173716' stand for what? how can i create this number?

For delete comment i need to pass a http request. Which request are they talking about? any example for it?

Answer (score 0):

Moderation Setup

To use the moderation tool, you either need to connect a Facebook account or a Facebook app to your Comments plugin implementation.

**Setup using a Facebook Account**
Simply include the following meta tag in the  section of every document in which you use the comments plugin:

**A.** `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>`

OR

**Setup using a Facebook App**
**B.** `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}" />`

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation-setup-instructions